# Unknown diode identification (27 XD or XD 27 markings)

Tags: diodes

Very much a novice here. I was attempting to repair an integrated control unit board from a 1990 honda/acura integra, but alas what I was hoping to be an easy fix is turning into more than I can handle. There is a common issue with these ICU's and the capacitors leaking... should have been an easy fix.

Once I get the thing open, both capacitors don't really look like they have been leaking, but I did find some burn marks between the anode side of a diode and (?). The diode was also a bit corroded, and some slight pressure caused the cathode lead to break right off.

My main concern is even finding a replacement diode now. The only markings I see on the diode are "27 XD". I'm not having much luck on finding info about this.

The voltage drop (if im reading this right) is about .627 to .638, but i'm not quite trusting of those numbers.

Pics of board and diode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzoLF.jpg

Comment: Right off the bat, it's marked as ZD3 on the board, so it's a Zener Diode.

Comment: And based on a quick Google, it's likely a generic 2.7 Volt zener, hence the 27. A comparison of the capacitor voltage tolerances or a sketch of the circuit may confirm. It doesn't look too complex.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info.  I think the initial appearance made me think it was a normal diode, but now I see other markings for diodes that are simply "D#", while this type is all "ZD#". 

When selecting a replacement zener diode, is there anything else to consider, other than voltage?

Comment: Not sure. At the very least, wattage is important. Someone else may give a better answer.

Comment: I compared a 2.7v zener diode and the readings I get from just the multi meter are different enough to conclude that I will need more info.

Seems that potentially, my only option is to try and build a tester to determine the specs of this zener diode, if I am unable to locate a an actual diagram on this circuit.